# Select distinct id when using sum on another column?

Tags: sql

An order can consist of several rows and so the OrderId is not unique. How can I do a SUM and not have to GROUP BY in order for the SQL to parse correctly?

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderId, SUM(ProductPrice * ProductQuantity ) as Total
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY OrderId
```

If I take off the GROUP BY line then I get

```
'OrderDetails.OrderId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

**EDIT**

My desired outcome is if an order consisted of 2 products then it should output both rows.

The group by is outputting 1 row.

Comment: Why do you not want to group if it works?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the distinct.
You must have a group by when summing/counting with extra columns
You will get totals per order with the group by.


so
1-20.00
1-30.00
2-10.00

Will get 
1-50.00
2-10.00

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have an order table ?

Generally orders contain of the order and details (lines of the order), so you should do a join with the master table instead. This should work.

```
SELECT O.OrderID,  SUM(Od.ProductPrice * OD.ProductQuantity ) as Total
FROM Orders AS O INNER JOIN OrderDetails AS OD ON O.orderID = OD.OrderID
group by O.OrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select a non-aggregated column (in this case `OrderID`) and an aggregated column (`SUM(xxx)`) then you'll have to group by on the non-aggregated columns...

But when you groupBy, then the OrderID is going to be distinct anyway, as it will group all the other values together for each orderID.